# GNOME Multi-monitor not working after sleep

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I installed GNOME multi-monitor add on on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to use top bar in both monitors. But after wakeup from sleep or suspend, the top bar of second monitor stops working.

After I set configuration again, the second monitor stays with an blank space on the top:

[image: screenshot]

Every time my computer wakes up, I have to set configuration in GNOME and restart to work again.

Any ideas how to fix this?